# Having SQL Server choose and show one record over other

Tags: sql, sql-server

Ok, hopefully I can explain this accurately. I work in SQL Server, and I am trying to get one row from a table that will show multiple rows for the same person for various reasons.

There is a column called `college_attend` which will show either `New` or `Cont` for each student.

My issue: my initial query narrows down the rows I'm pulling by Academic Year, which consists of two semesters: Fall of one year, and Spring of the following to create an academic year. This is why there are two rows returned for some students.

Basically, I need to generate an accurate count of those that are "New" and those that are "Cont", but I don't want both records for the same student counted. They will have two records because they will have one for spring and one for fall (usually). So if a student is "New" in fall, they will have a "Cont" record for spring. I want the query to show ONLY the "New" record if they have both a "New' and "Cont" record, and count it (which I will do in Report Builder). The other students will basically have two records that are "Cont": one for fall, and one "Cont" for spring, and so those would be considered the continuing ones or "Cont".

Here is the basic query I have so far:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    people.people_id,
    people.last_name,
    people.first_name,
    academic.college_attend AS NewORCont,
    academic.academic_year,
    academic.academic_term,
FROM
    academic
INNER JOIN
    people ON people.people_id = academic.people_id
INNER JOIN
    academiccalendar acc ON acc.academic_year = academic.academic_year
                         AND acc.academic_term = academic.academic_term
                         AND acc.true_academic_year = @Academic_year
```

I'm not sure if this can be done with a CASE statement? I thought of a `GROUP BY`, but then SQL Server will want me to add all of my columns to the `GROUP BY` clause, and that ends up negating the purpose of the grouping in the first place.

Just a sample of what I work with for each student:

| People ID | Last | First | NeworCont |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12345 | Soanso | Guy | New |
| 12345 | Soanso | Guy | Cont |
| 32345 | Person | Nancy | Cont |
| 32345 | Person | Nancy | Cont |
| 55555 | Smith | John | New |
| 55555 | Smith | John | Cont |
| --------- | ------ | ------- | ---------- |

Hopefully this sheds some light on the duplicate record issue I mentioned.

Comment: You want group by, add all of the columns except this new/cont one, and then you can do a case statement to pick whatever logic you want (ex: SUM(CASE WHEN college_attend = 'NEW' then 1 else 2 end) to make it work as an aggregate.  You are effectively asking to group N rows into 1.

Comment: if you could add some sample data this would be so much simpler to understand and easier to propose answers for. Honestly it's like flying blindfolded - but so simply solved. Paste some sample data (for each of the 3 tables) - please don't use images. Ideally you would also show us the expected result  that should be achieved from that sample of data.  See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

Without sample data its awkward to visualize the problem, and without the expected results specified it's also unclear what you want as the outcome. Perhaps this will assist, it will limit the results to only those who have both 'New' and 'Cont' in a single "true academic year" but the count seems redundant as this (I imagine) will always be 2 (being 1 New term and 1 Cont term)

```
SELECT
      people.people_id
    , people.last_name
    , people.first_name
    , acc.true_academic_year
    , count(*) AS count_of
FROM academic
INNER JOIN people ON people.people_id = academic.people_id
INNER JOIN academiccalendar acc ON acc.academic_year = academic.academic_year
    AND acc.academic_term = academic.academic_term
    AND acc.true_academic_year = @Academic_year
GROUP BY
      people.people_id
    , people.last_name
    , people.first_name
    , acc.true_academic_year
HAVING MAX(academic.college_attend) = 'New'
    AND MIN(academic.college_attend) = 'Cont'
```

Comment: Thanks Paul! Actually, the count that will end up being provided will be the overall count of New and Continuing students that the query generates for the academic year. I will try your suggestion and report back :)

Comment: Ok, unfortunately this solution isn't working for me. I am now having syntactical issues no matter where I end up putting this.

Comment: what is the error (exact text of that)